# Portlets JSR specifications and Nexus PlayController

Tags: portlet

Searches on Google are yielding nothing on the

```
<portal:renderparams id="xyz" name="xyz" class="SomeFilter"/>
```

tag and moreover the

```
SomeFilter extends nexus.core.portlet.play.PlayController
```

is mysterious to me as the source of nexus is not available. Moreover, I cannot find Google results on nexus playcontroller.

Please help in finding the right documentation as I am stuck.

Comment: What is your actual question?  JSR 186 and JSR 268 are portlet specifications but do not provide any implementation.  Apache Pluto and Liferay are portal implementations, but I don't know which product you are talking about.  I'm assuming you are talking about the IBM Nexus web portal?